# Change the actual file for Logins

Tags: 7, theming

I have a site and I'd like to customize the login page. I'm using a customized version of the Stark Theme and I'd like to know if there is any way to change the actual file behind the login form so it looks a bit more uniform with the rest of the site. So without creating a new file and redirecting.

Any help?

Comment: You can do so with theme overrides but it depends on what you want to alter as to what you need to override. Is it the layout of the form you want to change, or the layout of the whole page, or something else?

Comment: what is different?

Comment: @rooby mainly looking to alter the layout and look, (link fonts, etc.). because the page layout was generated from my html.tpl.php

Comment: Look, and somewhat layout, can be modified just with css, but that is outside the scope of this site. You can also override the page.tpl.php specifically for that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [iTweak Login](https://drupal.org/project/itweak_login) module to customize the login page. This module have so many settings to customize login form page as well as login block.

You can also try [FreshLogin](https://drupal.org/project/freshlogin) module. It will provide a complete different template.It  can customize as you want.